# Error occurs every time I try to log in after updating

Tags: 8

I cloned a site locally, imported the database and run: "composer update --with-dependencies",

Got the following:

> [RuntimeException]
>   Could not scan for classes inside
>   "/home/www/sites/site/web/vendor/drexarj/disqus-php/disqusapi/" which
>   does not appear to be      a file nor a folder

then I run "drush updb -y".

There were a couple warnings:

> The following module is missing from the file system: aspambot
>   bootstrap.inc:268
>   The following module is missing from the file system: phpmailer
>   bootstrap.inc:268

Then I uninstalled recaptcha by typing:

"drush pm-uninstall recaptcha"

Tried to log in, but got the following unexpected error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   Error: Call to undefined function Drupal\commerce_price\bcmul() in
>   Drupal\commerce_price\Calculator::multiply() (line 75 of
>   modules/contrib/commerce/modules/price/src/Calculator.php).
>   Drupal\commerce_price\Calculator::multiply('107.000000', '1.00')
>   (Line: 140) Drupal\commerce_price\Price->multiply('1.00') (Line: 259)
>   Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderItem->recalculateTotalPrice() (Line:
>   133) Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderItem->setUnitPrice(Object)
>   (Line: 144) Drupal\commerce_order\OrderRefresh->refresh(Object) (Line:
>   92) Drupal\commerce_order\OrderStorage->doPreSave(Object) (Line: 389)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save(Object) (Line: 820)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save(Object) (Line:
>   391) Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->save() (Line: 114)
>   Drupal\commerce_order\OrderStorage->postLoad(Array) (Line: 249)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple(Array) (Line: 231)
>   Drupal\commerce_cart\CartProvider->loadCartData(Object) (Line: 184)
>   Drupal\commerce_cart\CartProvider->getCartIds(NULL) (Line: 172)
>   Drupal\commerce_cart\CartProvider->getCarts() (Line: 221)
>   Drupal\commerce_cart\Plugin\Block\CartBlock->getCacheTags() (Line: 86)
>   Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder->viewMultiple(Array, 'full', NULL)
>   (Line: 71) Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder->view(Object) (Line: 151)
>   Drupal\block\Plugin\DisplayVariant\BlockPageVariant->build() (Line:
>   259) Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array,
>   Object, Object) (Line: 117)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array,
>   Object, Object) (Line: 90)
>   Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object,
>   'kernel.view', Object) call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view',
>   Object) (Line: 111)
>   Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view',
>   Object) (Line: 156)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line:
>   68) Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
>   (Line: 57) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1)
>   (Line: 47) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 99)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line:
>   78) Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1)
>   (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1,
>   1) (Line: 52)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1,
>   1) (Line: 23) Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line:
>   666) Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

My question is: what can I do about this? I've repeated the process two times and got the same error.

Answer (score 4):

> Call to undefined function Drupal\commerce_price\bcmul() in Drupal\commerce_price\Calculator::multiply()

Drupal Commerce requires the [BC Math PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) - you don't have it in your current environment.

To fix, rebuild PHP with support for the BC Math extension.